# Discord.js permissionOverwrites not working but no error at all

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've been working on a ticket bot for our company and ended up not being able to update a user's permissions per channel.

I cannot find any problems and the code is working apart of the permissions perfectly. I'm using DiscordJS 12.5.1.

Here's my code:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'ticket',
  category: 'Ticket',
  description: 'Creates a new ticket.',
  aliases: ['new'],
  usage: 'new',
  userperms: [],
  botperms: [],
  run: async (client, message, args, prefix) => {
    const discord = require('discord.js');

    message.guild.channels
      .create(
        `ticket-${message.author.username}-${message.author.discriminator}`,
        {
          permissionOverwrites: [
            {
              id: message.author.id,
              allow: ['CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE'],
              allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
              allow: ['ATTACH_FILES'],
              allow: ['CONNECT'],
              allow: ['ADD_REACTIONS'],
              allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
            },
          ],
          type: 'text',
          // parent: 'category id',
        },
      )
      .then(async (channel) => {
        let category = client.channels.cache.find(
          (c) => c.name == '➣ Online Tickets' && c.type == 'category',
        );
        if (!category) throw new Error('Category channel does not exist');
        channel.setParent(category.id);

        // channel.permissionOverwrites.create(message.author.id, {VIEW_CHANNEL: true, SEND_MESSAGES: false});
        // channel.permissionOverwrites.create(message.guild.roles.everyone, {VIEW_CHANNEL: false});

        var embedParent = new discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle(`Beste, ${message.author.username}`)
          .setDescription(
            'Een van onze medewerkers helpt je z.s.m! Laat alvast een bericht achter zodat wij je zo goed mogelijk kunnen helpen. Om U zo goed mogelijk te kunnen helpen komen nu enkele vragen, gelieve deze te beantwoorden.\nReageer met 1️⃣ voor een technische vraag \nReageer met 2️⃣ voor boekhouding en juridische vragen.\nReageer met 3️⃣ voor een samenwerking.\nReageer met 4️⃣ voor overige vragen. \n\n ***LET OP: Als U errors krijgt op uw server, kunt U het beste een ticket aanmaken op de website: snip ***',
          )
          .setColor('007BFF')
          .setFooter(
            '© OnlineNode.nl 2021 - Ticket Systeem',
            'https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/735827815521452133/830082858470604870/logo_400x400.png',
          )
          .setTimestamp();

        channel.send(embedParent).then(function (embedParent) {
          embedParent.react('1️⃣');
          embedParent.react('2️⃣');
          embedParent.react('3️⃣');
          embedParent.react('4️⃣');
          //embedParent.react("5️⃣")
        });
        message.guild.channels.cache
          .find((c) => c.name == '┃-discord-logs')
          .send('New ticket has been submitted!');
      });
  },
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `permissionOverwrites` array has an object where you repeat the `allow` key several times:

```js
{
  permissionOverwrites: [
    {
      id: message.author.id,
      allow: ['CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE'],
      allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
      allow: ['ATTACH_FILES'],
      allow: ['CONNECT'],
      allow: ['ADD_REACTIONS'],
      allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
    },
  ],
  type: 'text',
}
```

As an object can't have two keys with the same name, it's basically the same as this:

```js
{
  permissionOverwrites: [
    {
      id: message.author.id,
      allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
    },
  ],
  type: 'text',
}
```

[`allow`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/PermissionOverwrites?scrollTo=allow) is an array of the permissions that are allowed for the user or role:

```js
{
  permissionOverwrites: [
    {
      id: message.author.id,
      allow: [
        'ADD_REACTIONS',
        'ATTACH_FILES',
        'CONNECT',
        'CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE',
        'SEND_MESSAGES',
        'VIEW_CHANNEL',
      ],
    },
  ],
  type: 'text',
}
```

Another error is that when you set the parent of the channel with the [`setParent`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=setParent) method, it overwrites the permissions you just added and sets them to the same as the parent channel.

The `setParent` method accepts [an options object](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/SetParentOptions) as its second parameter. One of its properties is `lockPermissions`. It tells whether to lock the permissions to what the parent's permissions are and its default value is `true`. To prevent synchronising permissions, you can set it to `false` instead, like this:

```js
channel.setParent(category.id, { lockPermissions: false });
```

Answer (score 0):

As Zsolt Meszaros mentioned, your permissions will need to be in an array.

```
message.guild.channels
      .create(
        `ticket-${message.author.username}-${message.author.discriminator}`,
        {
          permissionOverwrites: [
            {
              id: message.author.id,
              allow: [
                'ADD_REACTIONS',
                'ATTACH_FILES',
                'CONNECT',
                'CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE',
                'SEND_MESSAGES',
                'VIEW_CHANNEL',
             ],
            },
          ],
          type: 'text',
          // parent: 'category id',
        },
      )
```

Another thing, it is possible that your bot is setting the permissions, but then soon after inside your code, you changed the category the channel belongs in:

```
channel.setParent(category.id);
```

Also, I'm not sure, but there might be a chance that after you change the category, the permissions are being removed and then copied from what the category's permissions are, so you'll have to set the category before setting the permissions.